# How do I align text output in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a function which creates a little star table based on some data collected elsewhere in the program. While the table produces the correct output, since the number of characters in each number changes, it un-aligns the table. For example,

```
70-78: *****
79-87: ***
88-96: ****
97-105: **
106-114: ******
115-123: ****
```

Is there any way to align the stars so that the output is something like this:

```
70-78:   *****
79-87:   ***
88-96:   ****
97-105:  **
106-114: ******
115-123: ****
```

Here's how I currently print the table.

```
for x in range(numClasses):
    print('{0}-{1}: {2}'.format(lower[x],upper[x],"*"*num[x]))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`str.format` already has the possibility to specify alignment. You can do that using `{0:>5}`; this would align parameter `0` to the right for 5 characters. We can then dynamically build a format string using the maximum number of digits necessary to display all numbers equally:

```
>>> lower = [70, 79, 88, 97, 106, 115]
>>> upper = [78, 87, 96, 105, 114, 123]
>>> num = [5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 4]
>>> digits = len(str(max(lower + upper)))
>>> digits
3
>>> f = '{0:>%d}-{1:>%d}: {2}' % (digits, digits)
>>> f
'{0:>3}-{1:>3}: {2}'
>>> for i in range(len(num)):
        print(f.format(lower[i], upper[i], '*' * num[i]))

 70- 78: *****
 79- 87: ***
 88- 96: ****
 97-105: **
106-114: ******
115-123: ****
```

Actually, you could even use a single format string here with nested fields:

```
>>> for i in range(len(num)):
        print('{0:>{numLength}}-{1:>{numLength}}: {2}'.format(lower[i], upper[i], '*' * num[i], numLength=digits))
```

Comment: Is old string formatting the only way to embed a variable value within the braces of the new string formatting?

Comment: No, you could also use the new style formatting there as well, but then you would have to escape the braces, or use nested replacements instead—which I realized would be even better, so see the edit in my answer :)

Comment: Just for clarification, why do you have to set digits equal to itself?   You can use already defined variables elsewhere in the `.format()` function.

Comment: Yeah, my choice of the variable name did not really make that clear (changed it now). In `numLength=digits` the first part is the named parameter name; the second part is the value for the named parameter. So `digits=digits` would set the named parameter `digits` of the function to the value of the variable `digits`.

Comment: @poke I guess you meant  numLength=digits on the last line.

Comment: @Armut Good catch! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12):

This should do the trick. I assume there are clever ways.

```
print '70-78:'.ljust(10) + '*****'
```

You could also use `expandtabs()`

```
print ('70-78'+'\t'+ '*****').expandtabs(10)
```

Comment: or, for the OP's example: `print('{0}-{1}:\t{2}'.format(lower[x],upper[x],"*"*num[x]).expandtabs(10))`

Answer (score 1):

```
lower = [70, 79, 88, 97, 106]
upper = [78, 87, 105, 114, 123]
num = [5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 4]

for l, u, n in zip(lower, upper, num):
    print('{0:<9} {1}'.format('{0}-{1}:'.format(l, u), '*' * n))
```

http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 1):

Ok, while the solution I'm using is admittedly ad-hoc, it works, and scales better than the answers so far. Basically it's just the method VR17 suggested, but with a little more so that the tab size scales with the data set, and isn't just hard coded in.

First I made a method that returns the number characters in some number.

```
def charNum(number):
    return math.floor(math.log(number,10)+1)
```

Then I used the `charNum()` function on the last point of my `lower` and `upper` data sets. Only the last point had to be used on each list because the last point is the biggest number. I then counted the character that weren't numbers(the dash, semicolon, and space), and adjusted accordingly.
So the final tabLength variable looks like this:

```
tabLength = charNum(lower[-1])+charNum(upper[-1])+3
```

I then plugged the `tabLength` variable into the `expandTab()` function to get proper spacing. Here's some example output:

```
1-11:  *******
12-22: *
23-33: ***
34-44: **
45-55: ***
56-66: *

99-249:   *****
250-400:  ****
401-551:  **
552-702:  **
703-853:  *
854-1004: ***

99-200079:      ******
200080-400060:  **
400061-600041:  ****
600042-800022:  **
800023-1000003: *
```

The only problem I can really see with this is that if I wanted to expand this to a table or something the tabs would be all funky. If I did that though, I'd probably look into `ljust` and `rjust`which I'm not all that familiar with right now. I'll leave the question open for a little while in case someone comes up with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way (in your case) would be to put a tab instead of space:

```
for x in range(numClasses):
    print('{0}-{1}:\t{2}'.format(lower[x],upper[x],"*"*num[x]))
```

Another way would be to use `str.ljust`:

```
for x in range(numClasses):
    label = '{0}-{1}:'.format(lower[x], upper[x])
    print(label.ljust(10, ' ') + "*" * num[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a relatively generic function for this kind of task based on the responses above.

```
def CreateAlignedTableString(table):
  """
  Create a nicely formatted table from a list of tuples or a list of lists.
  """
  max_col_width = [0]*len(table[0])
  for row in table:
    for col in range(len(row)):
      max_col_width[col] = max(max_col_width[col], len(str(row[col])))

  fmt_string = ''
  for col in range(len(table[0])):
    fmt_string += '{:%d} '%(max_col_width[col]+2)
  fmt_string += '\n'

  table_str = '' 
  for row in table:
    table_str += fmt_string.format(*row)

  return table_str
```