# How to align data properly while printing in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a python code to print names and ages in different columns. The names and ages are stored in separate lists. The issue is, data gets aligned improperly while printing. I want data to be aligned properly in every column.Please suggest how do i modify the code to get proper output.

```
name=['pav sunny','sham sunny','mala','shalu']
age=[25,56,52,50]
print('''NAME\t\tAGE\n''')
for i in range(len(name)):
      print(name[i],'\t\t',age[i])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I align text output in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091446/how-do-i-align-text-output-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

well, you get the longest name with `max()`, then the length of the longest name, then you do some `.ljust()` and `.rjust()` and that's it, example:

```
name=['pav sunny','sham sunny','mala','shalu']
longest_name = max(name, key=len)
max_lenght = len(longest_name)
age=[25,56,52,50]
print('NAME'.ljust(max_lenght, ' '), '\t\t', 'AGE')
for i in range(len(name)):
      print(name[i].ljust(max_lenght, ' '), '\t\t', str(age[i]).rjust(3,' '))
```

this will output:

```
NAME             AGE
pav sunny         25
sham sunny        56
mala              52
shalu             50
```