# how to get aligned output of two list?

Tags: python, list, alignment

la=["ngsir","raise","kajggf","kajggsdda","kajgg","kajggkjabfkafku","kajgg","asakfaflg","as","sfowih","akjfglff"]

lb=["raise","kajggf","kajggkjabfkafku","cvsk","kajgg","asakfaflg","as","sfowih","akjfglff","kajggsdda","kajgg"]

print("team A:\t\t\t team B:")
for i in range(11):
print(la[i]+"\t\t\t"+lb[i])

i was expecting the two lists to be align, but got

team A:                  team B:
rohit                   raise
raise                   kajggf
kajggf                  kajggkjabfkafku
kajggsdda                       rohit
kajgg                   kajgg
kajggkjabfkafku                 asakfaflg
kajgg                   as
asakfaflg                       sfowih
as                      akjfglff
sfowih                  kajggsdda
akjfglff                        kajgg

instead, how can i align them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align two lists into separate columns, you can do the following:

```py
team1 = ['Team A:', 'person1', 'person2', 'person3'] 
team2 = ['Team B:', 'person4', 'person5', 'person6']
string = ''

# Using the zip function, we can loop through the teams that correspond together.
for t1, t2 in zip(team1, team2): 
    string += f'{t1}\t\t\t{t2}\n' # Append the string with a new row.

print(string)
```

Output:

```py
Team A:                  Team B:
person1                  person4
person2                  person5
person3                  person6
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the below solution achieves what you are looking for.

```
la=["ngsir","raise","kajggf","kajggsdda","kajgg","kajggkjabfkafku","kajgg","asakfaflg","as","sfowih","akjfglff"]

lb=["raise","kajggf","kajggkjabfkafku","cvsk","kajgg","asakfaflg","as","sfowih","akjfglff","kajggsdda","kajgg"]


longest = max(map(len, la))

print("team A:" + (longest - 6) * " " + "\t\tteam B:") 
for i in range(11): 
    print(la[i] + (longest - len(la[i])) * " " + "\t\t\t" + lb[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [just()](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-print-column-alignment/#use-the-just-function-to-print-with-column-alignment-in-python) Function to Print With Column Alignment in Python. Here we use `ljust`.

```
la=["ngsir","raise","kajggf","kajggsdda","kajgg","kajggkjabfkafku","kajgg","asakfaflg","as","sfowih","akjfglff"]

lb=["raise","kajggf","kajggkjabfkafku","cvsk","kajgg","asakfaflg","as","sfowih","akjfglff","kajggsdda","kajgg"]

print("team A:\t\t\t team B:") 
for i in range(11): 
    print(la[i].ljust(25)+lb[i])
```

**Output:**

```
team A:                  team B:
ngsir                    raise
raise                    kajggf
kajggf                   kajggkjabfkafku
kajggsdda                cvsk
kajgg                    kajgg
kajggkjabfkafku          asakfaflg
kajgg                    as
asakfaflg                sfowih
as                       akjfglff
sfowih                   kajggsdda
akjfglff                 kajgg
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How do I align text output in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091446/how-do-i-align-text-output-in-python) for more options. In your case, the following should work:

```
la=["ngsir","raise","kajggf","kajggsdda","kajgg","kajggkjabfkafkujkgflsk","kajgg","asakfaflg","as","sfowih","akjfglff"]

lb=["raise","kajggf","kajggkjabfkafkugfdfs","cvsk","kajgg","asakfaflg","as","sfowih","akjfglff","kajggsdda","kajgg"]

max_space = len(max((la),key=len))+2 #adding 2 as the default space between the columns

str = "{0: <%d} {1}"%max_space
print(str.format("teamA:","teamB:")) 
for i in range(11): 
    print(str.format(la[i],lb[i]))
```